# How to make changes at the particular index of a list whose data is fetched from cloud Firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my flutter application, i fetched my data in a list from Firestore and now want to an ADD or REMOVE option for increasing or decreasing the number of units of that particular item on the list but after several tries not able to do that as the count on the entire list gets updated not that particular element in that index. Can anyone help me in this

```
CustomScrollView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index){
                      return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0,left: 15.0,right: 15.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].documentID,style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "DelishN", fontSize: 15.0),),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            width: 2.0,
                            color: Colors.black
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(23.0)
                        ),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                add();
                              },
                              mini: true,
                              child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 7.0,
                            ),
                            Text(_n.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'DelishN',),),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 7.0,
                            ),
                            FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: (){
                                minus();
                              },
                              mini: true,
                              child: Icon(Icons.remove, color: Colors.black,),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,)
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
            );
                    },
                    childCount: snapshot.data.documents.length))],
              )
```

Comment: Could you share code enough so it is reproducible, you can check the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You need to provide some of your code snippets brother...

Comment: Yes, I added the code snippet...

Comment: Is your question about having add/remove in the app or on how to edit the value on firestore afterwards?

Comment: about having add/remove button in the list that would increment/decrement the no. of units of that particular item, not the unit count of all the items in the list.